# retro tv show I can’t remember the name of

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

When I was a little younger I was watching a retro cable channel and a show came on that I was immediately interested in. The episode started with a team fighting a monster and after they defeat it they have the rookie clean up the evidence and he mops up the monsters blood and pours it into a river that connects to a town and it contaminated the town’s water, eventually people drink the water and start mutating into monsters that start attacking people. The team finds out and quickly make a cure in which the rookie drinks it trying to be helpful but ends up mutating but he’s still in control of himself. Long story short the show ends with them curing the town and the rookie uses his mutation abilities to help the team

Comment: Live-action or animated? If animated, looked like Japanese anime or western cartoon? Roughly when would this have been created?

Comment: It was a western cartoon that looked like it was made in the 90s

Comment: This could almost be a _[Treehouse of Horror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehouse_of_Horror)_ episode.

Comment: Science fiction or fantasy or a bit of both?

Comment: It was science fiction